# How do I enumerate through a directory in Objective-C, and essentially clear out all the directories of non-directory files?

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

How do I iterate through a folder (with subdirectories that might have further subdirectories in them) and delete the file if it's not a directory? Essentially, I'm asking how to clear all the directories. I'm having a little trouble with the `enumeratorAtPath:` method in this regard, because I'm not sure how to ask the enumerator if the current file is a directory or not. Does require looking through the `fileAttributes` dictionary. Note: This may be very wrong of me, but I initialize the enumerator with an NSString of the path. Does this change anything?

Comment: What, specifically, are you having trouble with? Both `NSDirectoryEnumerator` and `NSFileManager` have methods that will give you file attributes, from which you can test for directory status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
NSURL *rootURL = ... // File URL of the root directory you need
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnumerator = [fm enumeratorAtURL:rootURL
                    includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
                    options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                    errorHandler:nil];

for (NSURL *url in dirEnumerator) {
    NSNumber *isDirectory;
    [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];
    if (![isDirectory boolValue]) {
        // This is a file - remove it
        [fm removeItemAtURL:url error:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `enumeratorAtURL:...` like this is simpler than using `enumeratorAtPath:`, because `enumeratorAtURL:...` returns absolute URLs.  `enumeratorAtPath:` returns relative paths, which you can only pass directly to `removeItemAtPath:error:` if you're enumerating the current directory.